# Browser permissions for GetUserMedia from different camera devices

Tags: javascript, html, webapi

In the site I am coding, I want the user to have the option of toggling between different video input devices and view the stream.
I am able to enumerate all the devices using `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` and filtering this by kind gives me the video input devices.

However, when I try to use
`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { deviceId: deviceIdOfSelectedDevice }})`, I notice that I only get the stream of the camera allowed by the browser irrespective of the deviceId. I want to prompt for browser permissions to allow a different camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) says this about your code:

> The above will return the camera you requested, or a different camera if that specific camera is no longer available.

The document also says that you can require a device with `exact`:

```
{ video: { deviceId: { exact: deviceIdOfSelectedDevice } } }
```